# RSA шифрование

Tags: c#, криптография, rsa

Если у меня есть к примеру простые множители: p(1119182087) q(1861375333), их произведение (m)2083217929877259971 и e(5), как мне имея эти данные зашифровать сообщение с помощью публичного ключа? Кто может дать пример кода?

Comment: Я могу переписать мат часть из конспекта, но думаю, Вам будет удобнее в таком варианте. http://www.e-nigma.ru/stat/rsa/

Comment: Если Вам нужна только формула шифровки то   
C=m^e mod n  
где   
С- шифрованный текст
m- исходное сообщение
e, n - открытый ключ
Но не забывайте, что Вам нужен еще закрытый ключ d.
А расшифровуется по той же формуле, только на месте m стоит C, а на месте e стоит d

Comment: Посмотрите: - [RSA Implementation in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16070790/rsa-implementation-in-c-sharp) - [C# RSA encryption/decryption with transmission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17128038/c-sharp-rsa-encryption-decryption-with-transmission).